# Do you pay for GCP Out Bandwidth when serving 204 responses?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a GCP App Engine running that serves a bunch of GET endpoints with a `Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400` header. I notice that often, the responses are served from Google Edge Network and logged with a `204` code.

My question is, do these responses still count towards the `Out Bandwith` quota, or are they treated differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Frontend will cache content when Cache-Control is set to **public**.

Traffic delivered by Google services counts to your network egress quotas and costs. An HTTP 204 response is an egress network activity.